# Flutter: How to change the height of the cusror in the TextField

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

[image: TextFiled Screen Shot]

There is a property for changing the weight of the TextField cursor. Same I want to increase the height of the TextField cursor. Is there any way to do it ??

**Here is the sample code of my TextField**.

```dart
TextField(
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    border: OutlineInputBorder(),
    labelText: 'Username',
  ),
)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is cursorHeight argument that you can set for the `TextField` widget:

```
TextField(
  cursorHeight: 30, //you can play with the number to get the result you want
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    border: OutlineInputBorder(),
    labelText: 'Username',
  ),
);
```

Default result:

[image]

Result with the code above:

[image]

Comment: There is no property like cursorHeight for the TextField in Flutter. I'm using version 1.20.3

Comment: I used DartPad for the example and cursorHeight is available there. I found this issue on Github: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/26870

Comment: Yaa that's true. It is available on DartPad. Here important thing is DartPad is based on (1.21.0-9.2.pre). And current stable release is 1.20.3. So hopefully in next stable version cursorHeight property will be there.

Comment: Yeah I think so. If you find any solution based on version 1.20.3 please update the question and let me know as well

Answer (score 0):

Guess the accepted answer is outdated...

```
TextField (style: TextStyle(height: 1.2))
```